# Dynamically adding a video element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

EDIT: People have correctly pointed out I was using the wrong type for the video files I was using before. I now realize that if I want to use youtube videos I need to use the iframe tag

I'm having trouble creating the source tag and appending it inside the video tag. Right now my src is being added inside the video tag like this

```
src= "[object Object]"
```

I'm loading my data from a json array. I'm also loading some other data from my json array which you will see in the code below.
My jQuery

```
function postContent(data) {
  var $h2 = $("<h2>");
  var $div = $("<div>");

  $h2.html(data.title);
  $div.addClass("imgPlaceholder " + data.color);

  var $h3 = $("<h3>");
  var $src = $("<src>");

  $h3.html(data.videoTitle);
  $src.html(data.videoSrc);
  alert($src);
  var video = $('<iframe />', {
      id: 'video',
      src: data.videoSrc,
      //type: 'video/mp4', This was needed when I used the video tag
      //controls: true
    });

    //$src.appendTo($('#video')); This broke the page 

    $("#display")
        .append($h2)
        .append($div)
        .append($h3);

        video.appendTo($('#display'));
```

Here is my html

```
<div id="wrapper" class="group">
    <h1></h1>
    <hr>
    <ul id="menu"></ul>
    <div id="display"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my json array EDIT: changed src to youtube videos

```
{
"appTitle": "Content Navigator",
"posts": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Content 1",
  "videoTitle": "Video Title 1",
  "color": "orange",
  "videoSrc": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRSYU4YSISA",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Content 2",
  "videoTitle": "Video Title 2",
  "color": "purple",
  "videoSrc": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WijDExREruo",
},
```

Comment: if your video sources are .webm files you probably want to change the video element's type attribute to 'video/webm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`video`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) source path directly and not with an `src` element.

And as you are using `WebM` videos you need to change the type.

```
var video = $('<video />', {
  id: 'video',
  src: data.videoSrc,
  type: 'video/webm',
  controls: true
});
```

When you want to embed an youtube video into your page you have to do it differently. Copy the html like in the picture.

[image]

It looks like this.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T-Lvyr0OCT8" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Copy the attributes into your javascript and use and `iframe` instead of an `video` tag.

```
var video = $('<iframe/>', {
  id: 'video',
  src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/P3y8vc-3iVU',
  width: 560,
  height: 315,
  allowfullscreen: ''
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is working now. The links I was using were just examples. In my final version I'm probably going to use youtube videos. It looks like all I need to do is switch my video tag to an iframe

Comment: @OmegaCollision youtube is also working with to html5 tag video. they are just working with an other type. But it seems like they restrict direct acces to the source so yes you will have to use the iframe they show you when you click share

Comment: For some reason the iframe isn't working for me. I updated my OP to reflect the changes. When I inspect element the iframe tag looks fine but theres an element nested inside called #document. I have no idea where this is coming from or why my iframe appears blank on the webpage

Comment: @OmegaCollision you cannot directly use the link of the video. you must copy the ifame when you click the share button and go to the second tab

Comment: You're the man. Everything's all good I really appreciate it!

Comment: @OmegaCollision Allways a pleasure to help

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you've commented out this line:

```
//$src.appendTo($('#video'));
```

Replace it with:

```
$src.appendTo($video);
```

I need you to replace it because you're looking for an element with id of video which has not been created yet in the DOM.

Anyway, check it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $src = $("<src>");
// ...
$src.html(data.videoSrc);
```

These lines in your code create a jQuery object for a `<src>` element and then fill it with your video source, so the HTML element you'd essentially be getting is this:

```
<src>http://i.imgur.com/H0ibdlc.webm</src>
```

You don't need to do any of this. `data.videoSrc` is just a string, and the src attribute in a video element expects just a string. Just reference it directly when creating your video element:

```
var video = $('<video />', {
  id: 'video',
  src: data.videoSrc,
  type: 'video/webm',
  controls: true
});
```

Comment: You are correct. I edited my OP because I realized I needed to use a different tag if I want to link youtube videos. The video url shows up inside the iframe tag when I inspect the page element. However, all I see is a square outline where the video should be